# Objective C debugging not taking the proper step over route

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C.In detail I am reading about objective c from past three days. The below mentioned method is to generate prime numbers till a particular mentioned number as per the Seive of Erastosthenes algorithm.I am trying to debug the program but when ever the code comes to the line

"if(product > size )"

the next step will immediately take it to the

"for(j=2 ; j<= size ; j++ )"

I dont know what is going wrong with the debug.It goes into the break when the product is greater than the size.But when the condition is false (product > size) why doesn't it go to the next if condition that is

if(array[product-1] != 1)

Do I need to recompile the code.I am using xcode to debug the code on mac os X 10.x

---

@interface SeiveofErastosthenes : NSObject 
{

```
int* array;
int size;
```

}

-(SeiveofErastosthenes*) initMe: (int) ssize;
-(void) calculatePrimeNumbers;
-(void) print;

@end

-(void) calculatePrimeNumbers
{
    int product=0;
    int i=0;
    int j;

```
memset(array,0,size);
array[0]=0;
array[1]=2;

for(i = 1 ; i < size ; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 1)
        continue;

    array[i] = i+1;

    for(j = 2; j <= size ; j++ )
    {

        product = (i+1) * j;

        if(product  > size)
        {
            break;
        }

        if(array[product-1] != 1)
        {
            array[product] == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'Load symbols lazily' is unchecked in Xcode preferences -> debugging. It can sometimes wreak havoc.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode projects are set up with `-Os` optimization (optimize for speed and space) by default, for **both** Debug and Release builds, bizarrely. This kind of optimization will make debugging difficult, as code may be reordered for performance. Check your project and target settings for the "Debug" configuration, and make sure `Optimization Level` is set to "None."

Comment: I even put the optimization to "None" -00 but still it does the same.

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys I figured out the problem
Objective C debugger sucks

In my program

if(array[product-1] != 1)
{

```
 array[product] == 1;
```

}

It doesn't execute a statement if it is not necessary according to it

"array[product] == 1;" this is wrong according to the algorithm  but it is still a valid code

This is a valid statement according to c and it should execute it and the value returned is a boolean true or false.Objective C just ignores it and goes to the next loop.It is so intelligent that it even doesn't check the condition if( array[product] !=1 )

Comment: How is that indicative of a debugger that sucks? It sounds more like you have an issue with the compiler. Are you building using the “Debug” build configuration? If not, try compiling the code with no optimization when you debug; that’ll prevent this unexpected behavior.

Comment: That line does nothing and is likely optimized out by the compiler.  It has nothing to do with the debugger.